# Can I call reference unitofwork in DDD domain services?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In a case that a user must be created and persisted before send an email confirmation, is it ok to implement this behavior in a Domain service like below:

```
    using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Monex.Domain.Identity.Aggregates;
using Monex.Domain.Identity.Exceptions;
using Monex.Domain.Identity.Repository;
using Monex.Domain.Identity.SeedWork;

namespace Monex.Domain.Identity.Services {
    public class UserService {
        readonly IUserConfirmationService _confirmationService;
        readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public UserService (IUserRepository userRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserConfirmationService confirmationService) {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _confirmationService = confirmationService;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public async Task CreateUser (string email, string password, string city) {
            var emailExists = await _userRepository.CheckEmailExists (email);
            if (emailExists)
                throw new EmailAlreadyRegisteredException ();
            var newUser = new User (Guid.NewGuid (), email, password);
            var confirmation = newUser.CreateEmailConfirmation ();
            _userRepository.Add (newUser);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChanges ();
            await _confirmationService.SendEmail (confirmation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally practiced mechanism is not to let Domain Services interact with infrastructure - they typically do not deal with Transactions and Unit of Work. They belong in the domain model layer alongside aggregates, handle complex use cases that usually involve more than one aggregate and should be devoid of infrastructure concerns, including persistence and notifications.

Application services should be the ones doing this job. They should call into the Domain model layer (either into services or aggregates), gather the changed items, and handle the persistence as a transaction.

From your example, you should probably treat `UserService` as the Application Service, call a `factory method` in `User Aggregate` to create a new user object, and then persist it with the help of a `repository`.

Now to the good part:

- An interesting pattern I have used in the past is to treat notifications (like sending emails) as part of the Unit of Work itself. The UoW not only commits all data changes but is also responsible for dispatching "registered" notifications. You would only register/submit the notifications and let the UoW do the actual sending, after a successful commit.
- A better pattern is to publish an event with the relevant details and use a subscriber to construct and dispatch the notification.

Comment: Repository and Sending emails is all infrastructures stuffs, any call to these interfaces (IRepository, IUnitOfWork) should be done in application layer and never in the domain ?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Helps to imagine that you have infinite, permanent RAM memory and the entire domain layer to be living on the RAM at all time. No persistence required, no transactions necessary.  Only data and behaviour.